# Configuring Git

Tags: git

Never used Git before, I'm trying to use it in conjunction with `Composer` to download Yii 2 and I'm getting the error:

`git not found, check it's installed and in your path.`

I have it installed on `C:\program Files (x86)` - Downloaded from here http://git-scm.com/download/win

I am using XAMPP, so my webroot folder is - `C:\xampp\htdocs\`

Do I just need to move my Git folder? If so where to? Or do I need to do something else?

Apologies if this is simple, new territory for me though.

Jonnny

Comment: I'm not familiar with Git, but perhaps there's some sort of configuration file that needs to be configured with the correct git executable. Also, you can try creating an alias for `git` to work from wherever. That might work as well.

Comment: Where did you download git? There are several download packages available, for different environments.

Comment: Downloaded it from here: http://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't able to execute it because the path to the Git executable is not in your PATH environment variable. The installation of Git on Windows by default installs the **Git Shell** application, which you'll need to open to execute Git commands from.

If you'd like to execute Git commands from the standard Windows Command Prompt, you can either  [add the path to the Git directory to the PATH environment variable](http://blog.countableset.ch/2012/06/07/adding-git-to-windows-7-path/), or reinstall Git and select the option **Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt** during the installation.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I shall have a go with this

Comment: Thanks for your help and not just trying to close the question.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you!