# Can I use command-line Git tools and TortoiseGit simultaneously?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Sometimes information regarding git are more detailed and easier accessible when using git-bash than using TortoiseGit.
Therefore, I would want to use git-bash for very specific issues (e.g. creating a branch/checkout at the same time and commit uncomitted changes).

```
git checkout -b my_new_branch
git commit
```

Could I work with TortoiseGit without any problems afterwards? And vice versa?

Comment: In your place I used cygwin.

Comment: Note that Git bash is nothing more than port of the [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) shell to Windows.  What you run in Git bash are just regular programs shipped with Git for Windows (with `git` being the major top-level one).  You can easily run these commands in plain shell (`cmd.exe`) or in any 3rd-party shell emulator (like `Console`) on in PowerShell etc. The only requirement to do so is to tick the correct setting in the GfW installer as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20165901/720999).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. tortoise-git is just a user interface to the command line tools which just interpret the `.git` subdir in your project's directory. You can use them both on the same project, though running actions *concurrently* might cause problems, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this FAQ question](https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#nongitforwindowsunsupported) I would say it depends on what kind of git implementation you are using.